# Sun Lighting in Cycles render

Tags: light

I'm following a tutorial but it appears to be in an older version of Blender, under the cycles render, I have my Lamp set to Sun but I am unable to find an option to control its strength, I've looked online but wasn't successful in finding and answer, can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Darren.

Answer (score 4):

I found out, one has to enable *Use Nodes* button (either in Properties editor or in the Node editor with lamp selected) which will make *Emission* and *Lamp Output* nodes appear in the node tree used to control strength information.

Comment: how about a screenshot though